# How to get rid of attribute when it has no value, while transforming my XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to transform my XML using XSLT which should have **id** only if my **RefID** has value.

My input XML is having some id formatting that need as specified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LearningStandards>
    <LearningStandardItem xml:lang="en" RefID="B27A44AF14">
        <RefURI>L/K/2/d/</RefURI>
        <StatementCodes>
            <StatementCode>BB.DDD-K1.K2.L.1</StatementCode>
        </StatementCodes>
        <Statements>
            <Statement>Demonstrate command of the conventions.</Statement>
        </Statements>
    </LearningStandardItem>
    <LearningStandardItem xml:lang="en" RefID="">
        <RefURI>L/K/2/d/</RefURI>
        <StatementCodes>
            <StatementCode></StatementCode>
        </StatementCodes>
        <Statements>
            <Statement>Determine or clarify.</Statement>
        </Statements>
    </LearningStandardItem>
    <LearningStandardItem xml:lang="en" RefID="">
        <RefURI>L/K/2/d/</RefURI>
        <StatementCodes>
            <StatementCode />
        </StatementCodes>
        <Statements>
            <Statement>Determine or clarify.</Statement>
        </Statements>
    </LearningStandardItem>
    <LearningStandardItem xml:lang="en" RefID="C2F4CDD0">
        <RefURI>L/K/2/d/</RefURI>
        <StatementCodes>
            <StatementCode>DDSS.KLSA-LLta.KWTS.11-12.10</StatementCode>
        </StatementCodes>
        <Statements>
            <Statement>Determine or clarify.</Statement>
        </Statements>
    </LearningStandardItem>
</LearningStandards>
```

To transform i have my XSLT as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output doctype-public="urn:pubid:eleducation.org:doctypes:dita:topic"
        doctype-system="topic.dtd" indent="yes" method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LearningStandards">
        <topic>
            <title />
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </topic>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LearningStandardItem">
        <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </bodydiv>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="LearningStandardItem/@xml:lang" />
    <xsl:template match="@RefID">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RefURI">
        <p outputclass="RefURI">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="StatementCodes">
        <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </bodydiv>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="StatementCode">
        <p outputclass="StatementCode">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Statements">
        <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </bodydiv>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Statement">
        <xsl:variable name="code"
            select="../preceding-sibling::StatementCodes[1]/StatementCode" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string(@code)=null">
                <p outputclass="Statement">
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </p>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <p outputclass="Statement"
                    id="{string-join(tokenize($code, '\.')[position() >= last() - 1], '.')}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </p>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After transformation my output XML looks like this. Which has all the **"id"** attribute with null values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic>
    <title />
    <body>

        <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem" id="B27A44AF14">
            <p outputclass="RefURI">L/K/2/d/</p>
            <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
                <p outputclass="StatementCode">BB.DDD-K1.K2.L.1</p>
            </bodydiv>
            <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
                <p outputclass="Statement" id="L.1">Demonstrate command of the
                    conventions.
                </p>
            </bodydiv>
        </bodydiv>

        <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem" id="">
            <p outputclass="RefURI">L/K/2/d/</p>
            <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
                <p outputclass="StatementCode"></p>
            </bodydiv>
            <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
                <p outputclass="Statement" id="">Determine or clarify.</p>
            </bodydiv>
        </bodydiv>

        <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem" id="">
            <p outputclass="RefURI">L/K/2/d/</p>
            <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
                <p outputclass="StatementCode"></p>
            </bodydiv>
            <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
                <p outputclass="Statement" id="11-12.10">Determine or clarify.</p>
            </bodydiv>
        </bodydiv>

        <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem" id="C2F4CDD0">
            <p outputclass="RefURI">L/K/2/d/</p>
            <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
                <p outputclass="StatementCode"></p>
            </bodydiv>
            <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
                <p outputclass="Statement" id="11-12.10">Determine or clarify.</p>
            </bodydiv>
        </bodydiv>

    </body>
</topic>
```

But I need the Output XML to have **"id"** attribute only if it has values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic>
    <title />
    <body>

        <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem" id="B27A44AF14">
            <p outputclass="RefURI">L/K/2/d/</p>
            <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
                <p outputclass="StatementCode">BB.DDD-K1.K2.L.1</p>
            </bodydiv>
            <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
                <p outputclass="Statement" id="L.1">Demonstrate command of the
                    conventions.
                </p>
            </bodydiv>
        </bodydiv>

        <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem">
            <p outputclass="RefURI">L/K/2/d/</p>
            <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
                <p outputclass="StatementCode"></p>
            </bodydiv>
            <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
                <p outputclass="Statement">Determine or clarify.</p>
            </bodydiv>
        </bodydiv>

        <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem">
            <p outputclass="RefURI">L/K/2/d/</p>
            <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
                <p outputclass="StatementCode"></p>
            </bodydiv>
            <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
                <p outputclass="Statement">Determine or clarify.</p>
            </bodydiv>
        </bodydiv>

        <bodydiv outputclass="LearningStandardItem" id="C2F4CDD0">
            <p outputclass="RefURI">L/K/2/d/</p>
            <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
                <p outputclass="StatementCode">DDSS.KLSA-LLta.KWTS.11-12.10</p>
            </bodydiv>
            <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
                <p outputclass="Statement" id="11-12.10">Demonstrate command of the
                    conventions.
                </p>
            </bodydiv>
        </bodydiv>

    </body>
</topic>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `RefID` template to ignore empty attributes:

```
<xsl:template match="@RefID">
    <xsl:if test=". != ''">
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And your test in the `Statement` template should be

```
<xsl:when test="$code=''">
```

(not `string(@code)=null`, which is checking the *attribute* `code`, not your variable, and incorrectly testing for null instead of the empty string).